# simple_form without model and select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to create select which will be used just for search
form not be posted directly to the server here is the code from view:

```
= simple_form_for :tags, url: '#' do |f|
  = f.input 'id[]', collection: @tags
```

**@tags is just Active relation** - tags which comes from **acts-as-taggable-on**
here is my code from controller:

```
@tags = project.user_statuses.tag_counts_on(:tags)
```

from console looks like:

```
[#<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 1, name: "amazing">, 
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 2, name: "bfc-release">,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 3, name: "demo">,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 4, name: "awesome">,
 #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: 5, name: "project1">]
```

but I get 
    undefined method `id[]' for #
in my view. what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleForm tries to get value for this field. It takes object (`:tags`) and send it a method, named as field(`id[]`). So this lead to `:tags.send 'id[]'`. And because Symbol class doesn't have such method, you got error.

Perhaps it is bad idea to use simple_form_for in case when object is not model.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's a just bad syntax and non informative error message

It appear when I add "as: selectbox" option:

```
 = simple_form_for :tag, url: '#' do |f|
   = f.input 'ids',
     as: :select,
     collection: @tags,
     label_method: :name,
     value_method: :id,
     input_html: {:multiple => false}
```